# Reading Chrome Cache Data c#

Tags: c#, google-chrome

I am working on a an application where I need to open and read the Cached information that comes from Chrome.

What I am trying to achieve is to build an application where I can view the data below and chose which cache file to delete.

Below is the desired output that I need, which comes from Chrome itself, however, I need this to be accessible from a .Net application and am stuck.

```
HTTP/1.1 200
status: 200
content-type: image/jpeg
date: Mon, 18 Dec 2017 23:55:54 GMT
expires: Sat, 16 Dec 2017 15:01:29 GMT
access-control-allow-origin: *
last-modified: Tue, 12 Dec 2017 17:33:35 GMT
x-content-type-options: nosniff
server: snapshot_btfe
content-length: 2362
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
age: 47358
cache-control: public, max-age=86400
alt-svc: hq=":443"; ma=2592000; quic=51303431; quic=51303339; quic=51303338; 
quic=51303337; quic=51303335,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="41,39,38,37,35"
```

When reading the content At the moment, all I get is

> PvPÙÊÞÀqƒ¢q´‚ ÿ  ¼…       ø’  + :¶Q?ü¢ð" €`Ü €   €   €   €    D“Ô‰ ’Å           C                                  a…py}ÜÀ    ¾  ÅŒÀ    o   (ŒÀ       ‘Ãê¦Á}           googlemapsParamsÀ        „à      ÍÀ        „à‘`‰£)           define  ‘€Þq           jquery-wrapper  D“‰…p9„D…

I have also looked to see if it is a compressed gzip file too and get to open some files, but others will not open.

This is the code that I have at the moment, that opens some and not others.

```
static void Main()
{
    byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\simon\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\f_002063");
    byte[] decompressed = Decompress(file);

    string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decompressed);
    result.Dump();
}

static byte[] Decompress(byte[] gzip)
{
    using (GZipStream stream = new GZipStream(new MemoryStream(gzip),
        CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
        const int size = 4096;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int count = 0;
            do
            {
                count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, size);
                if (count > 0)
                {
                    memory.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                }
            }
            while (count > 0);
            return memory.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

The output from the decompressed file, shows me that this is a Jquery file based on the output

> /*! jQuery v2.0.3 | (c) 2005, 2013 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license
>   //@ sourceMappingURL=jquery.min.map
>   */
>   (function(e,undefined){var t,n,r=typeof undefined,i=e.location......

Any help progressing this would be greatfully received.

Comment: @SalomonZhang how do you mean?

Comment: From the info above, this is an image file, content-type: image/jpeg. It won't be read as text. If you want to see the image, you need to find something like ImageCacheViewer.

Comment: @SalomonZhang Yes, the file that i picked from using 'chrome://cache/' in chrome, because i dont know what this relates to I have no idea on what the file name is, so when coding I have been only able to select a random file and try and read it

Comment: I'd look around Chromium code for backend for clues: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/net/disk_cache/simple/simple_backend_impl.cc

Comment: did you ever got a solution or developing this? if so would you mind sharing the solution as I am in the same boat, TIA! @SimonPrice

Comment: @user1715559 I dont think I ever did get to the bottom of this. I cant see anything from that time where I was working that a solution came forward. I will look through some old stuff tomorrow and see if i can see if i can find anything

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a complete explanation for you, but in the cache folder, larger files are stored individually as f_xxxxx, while smaller files are combined as data_0, data_1, etc.  My guess is that you are properly decrypting the f_xxxx files, but not the data_x files?

If so, you can refer to this info to see how the files in data_x are combined:  http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Chrome_Disk_Cache_Format

I have never gone down this path, but it looks like the index file in the cache folder is an array of cache addresses that would give you a clue as to how to break up the data_x files.  You may need to grab only the bytes you need and then decompress those (rather than trying to decompress the entire file.)  That is my best guess and not confirmed, but the link might help you further.

Chrome stores most of its data in Sqlite databases, which are just regular files in the same general location as the cache.  You can use Sqlite studio to get a lot of valuable information, and you can use `System.Data.Sqlite` to work with this directly in C# once you have a sense of what you're trying to do.  I am unsure whether that will help you with the cache, but most of what I have needed to do programmatically with Chrome has been done using that library, or simple `File.Delete` operations.

Comment: Thanks, I have up voted the question and will take this under advisement and take a look and let you know how well I get on.

Answer (score 0):

The [JPEXS Opensource flash SWF decompiler](https://github.com/jindrapetrik/jpexs-decompiler) has Java code to do this at [in the source tree](https://github.com/jindrapetrik/jpexs-decompiler/tree/master/src/com/jpexs/browsers/cache) for both Chrome and Firefox (no support for Firefox's more recent cache2 though).